# Error occurred in deployment step 'Uninstall app for SharePoint': Only users who can View Pages can list Apps

Tags: 2013, error, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I am Developing a Provider Hosted app for the SharePoint 2013. In that I am facing this error while deploying the App.

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Uninstall app for SharePoint': Only users who can View Pages can list Apps.
```

I have Created the farm user, and also followed all configuration steps which were mentioned to be followed.

Can any one help me to solve this error? I am new to SharePoint.

Answer (score 3):

The user you are running Visual Studio with should at least have read permissions on pages of the SharePoint web where you are trying to deploy your app. (Easiest would be to add the user to the visitors or members group  like described here: http://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/helen-jones/2012/01/30/how-to-add-users-to-a-sharepoint-group#.UZm6TqYazCQ, the link is for 2010, but the only real difference is finding Site Actions now placed in the upper right corner looking like a gear)